# alternative to preg_replace with "e" modifier

Tags: php, regex

I have this line ...

```
preg_replace('/([^\x20-\x7e])/e', '"\\\\\\x" . dechex(ord("${1}"))', $string);
```

... and it is generating an warning about the use of preg_replace() with the /e modifier.

I am looking for some tips on how to replace this regex with an alternative.

I gather that "preg_replace_callback"can be used as an alternative but need some help with actually implementing it.

I have read the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) but still struggling and my question is one of what the relevant preg_replace_callback alternative to the original is.

Is this valid?

```
function myCallback($matches) {
    return '"\\\\\\x" . dechex(ord($matches[1]))';
}
preg_replace_callback('/([^\x20-\x7e])/', 'myCallback', $string);
```

Comment: *Is this valid?* Looks like that but it does not seem to be what you want. The function call is still inside the string. Just remove the surrounding single quotes. Otherwise it just returns this string literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return code, you return the actual value you want to replace with, like so:

```
function myCallback($matches) {
    return "\\\\\\x" . dechex(ord($matches[1]));
}
```